# Modeling 3D spaces in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, 3d

I'm new to OpenGL (OpenGL ES) & 3D modeling and I'm trying to create templates for closed spaces like a theater, auditorium etc to use in an iPad app. Doing this natively in OpenGL ES seems to be involving a nice learning curve to bridge.

Before I try doing this in Blender, SketchUp & the like, and then looking at options to import it in my app, I would really like to know what other practical options there are to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before I try doing this in Blender, SketchUp & the like, and then looking at options to import it in my app, I would really like to know what other practical options there are to do this. Please advice.

That's exactly what you should do. Model the objects in a modeling program, then load the data into a scene graph structure that directs a renderer to make the proper OpenGL drawing calls.

OpenGL is a drawing API that draws points, lines and triangles to the screen. Nothing more. There's no such thing like a scene in OpenGL, there are not even models.

Everything that defines a scene or models is outside the scope of the OpenGL API and must be implemented by you, or a 3rd party library.